# check value of cell from searched datatable

Tags: vb.net

I need to check if the first cell in the first col contains the characters "ND".. The cell can either contain "Rm####" or "Rm####ND". if the cell contains the "ND" characters then a picturebox on the form needs to be made visible.

this is the code that I am currently using to search the access database...
the search results alway only return one row of data from the datatable.
is there a way i can incorporate this with the search?

```
    Try
        Dim con As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source='\\SERVER\Drawings\Database\Drawing Database.accdb'")
        con.Open()
        Me.DrawingsTableAdapter.DrawingNumber2(Me.Drawing_DatabaseDataSet.Drawings, ("%" & TextBox2.Text & "%"))
        Me.Validate()
        Me.TableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(Me.Drawing_DatabaseDataSet)
        con.Close()
    Catch ex As System.Exception
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
```

Comment: What's the SQL for the DrawingsTableAdapter SelectCommand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe you lost single quotation marks
**"%'" & TextBox2.Text & "'%"**
see if it works

besides,I've never seen the function 'DrawingNumber2'
and not found on the Internet.
Too much self-defined code,not so understandable.